# Python Selenium - Identifying and Clicking Angular Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Utilizing Python and Selenium, I am attempting to click on the 'Matrix' and 'Transaction Desk' Angular buttons on a specific webpage (see screenshot). I have looked into this for hours now and have not found anything that has worked. It actually seems like there are a lot of unsolved questions still out there around this topic. The source code (see screenshot) does not appear to be within any iframe. The traceback just tells me that it could not find the specific code and times out.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Matt\\Documents\\WebDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.stellarmls.com/")

#Password authentication HERE, so you will be unable to access this site yourself.

driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="collapse911"]/app-links-panel-body/div/div/div[1]'))).click()

print(driver.page_source)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Splitt\ROI Property Finder.py", line 53, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="collapse911"]/app-links-panel-body/div/div/div[1]'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Matt\Python3.9\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Supplementary screenshots:

[image]

iframe:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's timing out on the element? You're sure the xpath is right? And is not in an iframe?

Comment: @DMart I have tried multiple variations of xpaths but to no avail. I even used the browers Selenium IDE. The current xpath just gives me a timeout error whereas the previous xpaths fired back a different error. I can run it back and share the SS if that would help. An iframe is used earlier on in the source code but nothing is directly included within it's brackets.

Comment: Even with a simple xpath, something like this: //h4[contains(@class, 'apptitle')] ? And again, no iframes involved?

Comment: The xpath that you provided raised the same timeout exception as the one included in the code currently. No iframes, that I could find that would affect this code. I will post the iframe that I did find in a moment.

Comment: If the element is in an iframe you need to switch_to that iframe. Plenty of examples on SO